# Android open Gmail app with specific email by id

Tags: android, email, android-intent, gmail

I've an Listview which contains all unread E-Mails from my Google Account. My plan is to start the Gmail-App with the specific E-Mail opened if the user clicks on it. Is there any way to start the Gmail-App and tell them to display a specific e-mail by its E-Mail-ID?

Thanks for helping,
J. Doe ;)